# What file system can be read/written by Vista and Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: windows, macos, ntfs, fat32

FAT32 was what I suggested, however that has a volume limit of 2TB, which we are quicky approaching. Is there any alternative that is reliable, with a minimum of modifications to either OS?

Comment: Can't set multiple answers as correct. Thanks John T and emgee. Was a bit unsure initially about ntfs-3g but following more reading it appears solid enough to reccomend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about NTFS? The only modification you'll need to make is on the OSX side of things, which is installing the [NTFS-3G](http://www.ntfs-3g.org/) driver. It's useful to have regardless, most GNU/Linux distributions come with it pre-installed now.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to NTFS-3G, there is software called Paragon NTFS is a paid for add-on to Leopard that would give read and write access to NTFS volumes. I'm wondering though what sort of setup you need right now where you have direct connected volumes to both Windows and OS X that would conceivably exceed 2TB in size. Because if it's directly connected to one, using SMB (already built in) you could connect to the other.